# Photoelectric effect: voltage vs current graphs

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I watched this youtube and I was kinda confused in the graphs that they used: *int refers to intensity
[image]

For this part, the red graph is meant to be the new one, and I'm not sure if the graph is just drawn incorrectly, and if the person making the video wanted the two graphs to intersect at the y intercept, but shouldn't the red line intersect higher? ie when there is no voltage applied, assuming the light has sufficient frequency to overcome the work function, wouldn't the red graph emit more photons per second and hence produce a higher current? This is because from what I know, the photocurrent increases with increasing intensity, hence at a higher intensity of light, shouldn't the photocurrent be higher? Thereby explaining why the y intercept of the Red line should be higher than the blue line?

and for this part:
[image]

It's kind of similar but shouldn't the green light intersect the y axis higher than the blue line? Similar to above, as the experiment from the green graph has the higher intensity, shouldn't the measured photocurrent be higher? Building on that, I don't understand how the two graphs can intersect to the right of the y axis, or just at all. Frequency doesn't affect the photocurrent right? (given the frequency is greater than the threshold frequency), so shouldn't that mean that the graph that has the higher intensity be constantly higher than the graph with the lower intensity? But it makes sense that the green graph has a lower stopping voltage so hence it should be under the graph on the left, but then again that doesn't make sense to me because I thought that the frequency didn't affect the photocurrent and hence the graph with the higher intensity should always have a higher photocurrent.

The youtube video didn't really address this, linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcdDE3FrHdg)

Was wondering if someone could please explain, thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question or further comment to explain why you believe the graphs should behave as you think they should? More explanation of your thinking would be helpful. Leaving a link to the YouTube video would also help greatly.

Comment: @flevinBombastus done :)